# Provide a bounty per answer, not just for accepted answer

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties

I asked [a question about paradigms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464022/when-to-use-and-not-to-use-each-development-paradigm) quite a while ago, and got zero useful answers. Since the question is an accumulator-type question (subjective and opinion but not a poll) I would like to offer a bounty for every (decent) answer provided (over and above the +1-thanks-for-contributing courtesy upvote), but of course this feature does not exist.

Anybody else want this kind of feature?

Example: for the referenced question, I would expect that there are a dozen or so paradigms worth mentioning, some of which i have no experience with at all, so I'd like to offer 50 or 100 points per answer to help get the information "out there"

I could ask a dozen or so questions, one per paradigm, but I'm way too <strike>lazy</strike> busy for that, plus I may overlook a paradigm or two that way.

EDIT: this is not a request for "supervotes", it's more like a multi-accept with a bounty. [though i like the idea of 'supervotes' for different purposes]

Comment: Sounds like you want supervotes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8098/should-we-have-a-small-number-of-supervotes-per-day

Comment: @[random]: negative on the "supervotes", this is not the same thing. see edit.

Comment: So it's kind of like divving up a bounty across several answers? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/accept-multiple-answers-or-split-bounty-among-several-users

Comment: @[random]: that's closer but still not quite the same; but one 'accepted' answer doesn't make sense for this kind of question...

Comment: Related: [Provide a means to reward users and their answers (decoupled from bounties)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239088/provide-a-means-to-reward-users-and-their-answers-decoupled-from-bounties/239089?noredirect=1#comment783626_239089).

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this proposal is that it gives more control to the question asker, which is good for the asker, but not so much for the answerer, because it introduces a great deal more uncertainty.

On regular bounty questions, as long as someone has more than 2 upvotes on their answer, they know with certainty that one individual will receive at least half the bounty amount for that question, or the entire amount if the owner selects an accepted answer.  No splitting.  They are competing for that guaranteed reward.  If you instead switch to a system where they may or may not receive a smaller bounty for each and every answer, then the playing field becomes much more varied.  Some askers may be very stingy with their multi-accepts, offering them only the minimal amount required.  Others may be very generous, offering them to pretty much anyone who provides an answer.

Not only does this introduce uncertainty into the reward scheme for bounties, it also sets up a situation where some individuals will be recognized as generous and (possibly) exploited for their multi-accepts, and reviled if they are withheld.  Others will be recognized as stingy.  We've already seen the impact that revealing the acceptance rate has on answerers' behavior.  Introducing another reason to consider who is asking rather than what is being asked seems, to me, to be unnecessary.

That said, it might be possible to come up with a way to implement this that is fair and minimizes the uncertainty for those providing answers, but it isn't immediately obvious to me what that would be.

Comment: 1/2 bounty for autoselect

Comment: @hyperslug: `Error parsing input: sentence fragment at line 1` ... Huh? :)

Comment: @Adam, sorry, I meant if the system selects the answer instead of the owner, only 1/2 the bounty is awarded.

Comment: @hyperslug: Thanks, updated my response. :)