# Ability to credit a post multiple times

Tags: feature-request, voting, privileges

I'm using Stack Overflow for a lot of years now, but sometimes I find upvoted answers which I found in the past and find again very helpful now.

I think it would be nice to give more credits to the answer and to upvote it again after a long time, like one year.

My main aspect is that I can give some credit directly, a bounty is nothing I have in mind since I would need to wait some time until I can do it. I want to do something "good" now, not in the future.

Comment: Related idea: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239088/provide-a-means-to-reward-users-and-their-answers-decoupled-from-bounties

Answer (score 18):

That's where [bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) are for. One of the stock reasons for posting a bounty:

> #### Reward existing answer
>
> One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty.

Comment: Well true, but it is not sooo much worth for me haha. As far I remember I still need to wait one week until I can give it right? Out of my view is another aspect is an increased visibility which I don't want to give, since it would create unnecessary noise.

Comment: @rekire I think you have to wait 48 hours (or was it 24?). A week is the maximum time to wait.

Comment: Too long out of my view for my I want to give some credit right now.

Comment: @rekire - So you are willing to wait a year to upvote the contribution but not 48 hours to award a bounty that is 5x the amount of a single upvote (at a minimum).  You have already upvoted the contribution.  Upvoting the same contribution multiple times is to easily abused.

Comment: @Ramhound you got me wrong I made a upvote a year ago and now I would like to upvote it a second time. Serial upvoting on a yearly basis is not really a problem out of my view.

Comment: Serial voting of any kind is a concern for the entire community.  If a contribution could be upvoted once a year, really bad contributions, could be downvoted once a year.  Regardless you would be waiting more than 48 hours for a feature like this to be rolled out. *The contribution is either worth a bounty or it isn't.*  If it's not worth a bounty it probably shouldn't receive multiple upvotes from the same user.

Answer (score 1):

This feature can easily be abused to inaccurately boost the display quality of posts. I mean, if it were like you suggested where users can upvote a post once a year, 10 years = 10 upvotes... *per voter*, a score that is considered high even for a 10 year old post.

I think, if you don't feel that a bounty is worth rewarding on a post that helped you multiple times, the post just might not be high quality enough to receive another upvote.

> I want to do something "good" now, not in the future.

I think the poster would be more than happier to receive a bounty in 24 hours than an upvote now!

Comment: To be honstest I'm not so active nower days that I would just visit stackoverflow to press on a button to give a bounty. It is also the wrong way. And seriosly you care about abusing voting on a yearly basis? I would guess 90% of the users don't use the sites for more then one year.

Comment: @rekire *"And seriously you care about abusing voting on a yearly basis?"* That's a valid point, but I believe it *can* be a problem in the future...