# Color kvotes differently (like kviews)

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, user-interface, voting, usability

For questions with >=1000 votes, I think the vote count should be colored just like kviews are.  See:

[image]

At first glance it looks like a question with 98k views and 286 answers has only 1 vote, which made me do a double-take.  I think the vote count should use the same coloring scheme as the views to help differentiate views from kviews.

For reference, [this is the question I'm referring to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c) though really it is only an issue in the question list views.

**EDIT**: resurrecting because I thought it'd be done by now, and thought with all the layout changes, maybe it had been rolled in unbeknownst to me and untagged here, but I'm still seeing it (after a minor (helpful!) edit I did to bump it)

[image: still broek halp;]

Comment: Huh.  Yeah...this suggestion seems like a straightforward no-brainer.  On the other hand, I've been wrong about these things before.

Comment: @beska, go with your gut on this one.  @Daniel +1

Comment: @beska I imagine there aren't many questions that have had kvotes before so it probably just hadn't come up yet.  In a few months you'll probably see me request the same thing for answers as well ;)

Comment: Specifically, there is only *one* question with over a thousand votes across all 4 sites. There are quite a few answers, but only one question.

Comment: What is the question with the most answers currently, anyway? So far it looks like this one with [640](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58640/) is, but is there any that is higher?

Comment: I'm still waiting for MegaVotes and MegaViews

Answer (score 9):

Would it be possible to just put the `k` after the number instead?

`1k

votes`

instead of

`1

kvotes`

**EDIT**
This should also be used on views to keep it consistent.
And, since it's already used on reputation `21.7k` it would be consistent with the rest of the site.

Comment: That's a decent suggestion but I'm just looking for consistency.  If they went with this, I'd expect the same for views.  I'd prefer the coloration because it's a more standout visual indicator.

Comment: Glad I'm the one making suggestions and not taking decisions =)

Comment: no, this was already discussed ad nauseam elsewhere; feel free to look it up.

Answer (score 6):

> At first glance it looks like a question with 98k views and 286 answers has only 1 vote

It does have one vote. One REALLY BIG vote.

(maybe a [superupvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8098/should-we-have-a-small-number-of-supervotes-per-day)?)

edit: but seriously, coloring is specific to views to make it more unique. Extending it to votes would make it less unique, and also, we don't really want things getting that many upvotes -- but views, yes.

Comment: I demand the "vote up by 1k" button now

Comment: I'm just wondering if it's worth reconsidering this. There's a lot more 1k questions now: http://i.stack.imgur.com/lk2DX.png

Comment: @Mysticial and more every time, this will be a problem more often every time, I opened a [dup](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155368/it-is-hard-to-spot-questions-with-1k-votes-in-the-profile-question-preview) by mistake plx Jeff consider this D:

Answer (score 2):

There's currently only 3 questions with more than a thousand votes, and a dozen more that have more than 500. Most of them are polling style questions that wouldn't be allowed nowadays.

Strangely enough, the Cthulhu question, which is a legitimate SO question, hasn't broken the 500 vote barrier yet.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that it's only applicable to a small few questions, but it'd be a relatively simple fix, and one that will become more pressing.  I figured with the recent facelifts, why not see if someone wanted to put this in as well.

Comment: @Are you sure it'll become more pressing?