# A voting corner-case when merging questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, down-votes, up-votes, merged-questions

Check out what I can do...

---

[image]

---

Yes, too many votes. I happened to be taking a swing through the [highest voted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711/what-is-the-single-most-influential-book-every-programmer-should-read) and noticed it. I'm fairly sure it's a result of [a prior merge](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1711/revisions).

If a question can end up with both an upvote and a downvote from a user due to a merge, it makes me wonder if it could also end up with multiple upvotes or downvotes from one user. Hey, it's the elusive [supervote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8098/should-we-have-a-small-number-of-supervotes-per-day)!

Maybe it's not a frequent enough occurrence to worry about fixing, but I just thought I'd point it out.

Comment: I'm pretty sure post merging handles multiple upvotes/downvotes from the same user; I think it's just when there's one in each direction that there's a problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug with question merge - I wasn't checking if a user had voted the opposite way when moving votes over.

I'll get a fix out for the data and the merge logic.

<sub>P.S. you *are* special!</sub>

**Edit**

Question merge will no longer move any up/down votes to the master question; all previously merged up/down votes will be deleted and scores fixed.

Favorites will still be transfered.

Comment: I knew it! I knew I was special!... Hey, wait a minute, which *kind* of "special" are you implying?

Comment: Moving votes made sense to me; is it not possible to still move votes but cancel out this particular case?

Comment: @Michael: while it would be possible to "fix" this case, we ultimately decided to no longer move any rep-bearing votes, because the master question's owner didn't do anything to merit those votes (especially downvotes).

Answer (score 2):

The SO team was trying out some quantum computers to host SE 3.0.

Your votes were caught in a corrupt branch of quantum processing and both eventualities emerged.

The bugs are being ironed out and your issue will be fixed shortly.

Thank you for filing the bug report.

Comment: Please note that in some cases it may be that the parallel dimension you inhabit is the extra one, and that in may be scheduled for termination due to the reality merge. We are terribly sorry for the inconvenience.