# Ability for the users with big rep to choose, how much reputation to decrease or to increase

Tags: feature-request, reputation, high-rep-users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should we have a small number of Supervotes per day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8098/should-we-have-a-small-number-of-supervotes-per-day)

As far as I see, there is fixed amount of reputation given by one user for a good question or decreased for a bad. I think, Stack Exchange should give the advanced users (> 2000 rep for example) an ability to upvote a question for more than 5 points and downvote for more than -2 points.

These people are experts, and their opinion should be estimated higher, than opinions of the users with low rep. Now they have the same amount of voice, which seems totally unfair to me because the voice of a good expert should be more appreciated, then of a common person.

So I think, we should give the highly rated people an ability to give increased votes, if they want. The quantity of rep of votes should be able to increase with the growing rep and decrease if it falls.

Comment: Nope, don't see why this would be needed. Everyone has one vote, and that vote is equal. New people can be experts too, everyone started at 1.

Comment: I'd abuse the hell out of this.

Comment: *"These people are experts"*...or simply have been here a long time.

Comment: than i want to give anyone 500k in single upvote

Comment: Let's implement that scoring system on this particular question and see how it goes. Trial balloon.

Comment: And let's make comment upvotes count towards rep, too. And helpful flags. And badges. And....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah guys, because [every vote has a right to live and must be cherished](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149621/the-current-review-system-encourages-fake-reviews-some-people-upvote-everything). No vote left behind, right?

Seriously - I'd actually support something like this if it were based on tag experience (= tag answer upvotes) instead of just rep. So if a user has plenty of upvotes in x tag, their vote on questions/answers in that tag count more. You get to do all sorts of things the more rep you have, so why not this?

Goodness knows the bike shed phenomenon is alive and well, and people vote on garbage all the time. I see this every day (especially in the PHP tag, but in others, too) where people post misguided questions (classical instances of the XY problem), and get heaps of equally misguided answers, earning tons of upvotes... while the one guy who says "you shouldn't be doing this in the first place" remains blithely ignored. It's not encouraging competent people to stick around.

Comment: You're more interested in the supervote affecting the _post_ score, then, as opposed to affecting the poster's rep?

Comment: Yes, tag answer upvotes is a good idea. Anyway, I still think, that current system with fixed scores can be improved, made more flexible. May be not in a way, I suggested.

Answer (score 5):

I don't want to have to click a choice when I place an upvote, this would take too much time for me to process every vote, and I vote a lot.

Comment: +819 to you, sir.

Comment: `+42` @AnthonyPegram

Comment: +911 to you sir

Comment: +(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1)

Comment: Fair point, but a "super upvote" feature could be implemented in a way that isn't an obstacle to regular voting

Comment: @Pekka웃, yes, but they would need to add one more thing to the upfront UI, and I would still have to ponder the decision (unless I just got in the habit of never using it).

Answer (score 3):

They already can, with the [bounty system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) they can award answers that deserve more than just the 1 rep with more rep.

Answer (score 0):

I dont want give 500k rep in a single vote and see a particular user have trillion billion rep or in other word its not a good idea also it will take extra time to choose how much rep to give per upvote