# Better badges for non-accepted answers

Tags: feature-request, badges

I don't think many people unaccept answers and pick a different one. Also, I think many people upvote the accepted answer just because it was accepted.

But I see a couple of silver badges (Guru, Englightened) that only apply to accepted answers, and it makes me wonder if that stops people from making further suggestions once a question has an accepted answer.

I guess I just wonder about which badges should really be sought after... perhaps badges for "first answer (with upvote from asker) on a question that's over 24 hours old", as a way of encouraging people to try to help out on older questions.

And more value placed on upvotes from the asker, rather than from peers.

So

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a response to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6662/how-to-give-some-boost-to-some-really-good-answers-that-arrive-late), one of my suggestions was a bronze badge akin to the necromancer, which would be awarded to an answer on an already accepted question that receives *n* upvotes.  The goal would be to encourage completeness in answers, even if the 15pts are off the table.

Answer (score 2):

Populist is a gold level badge that is rewarded for scoring 2x the amount of the accepted answer (with the minimum accepted answer being +10). This means that if someone has an accepted answer at +10, if you get +20 on the same question you can get a gold badge.

But in a more broad sense...all badges should be sought after, since they are supposed to be rewarding good behavior (the taxonomist badge is the only one that really has people wondering about potential gaming). Even peer pressure is in theory a good behavior because you are getting rid of bad content (that doesn't say that you can't put bad content up intentionally just to get voted down and get the badge, however).

Comment: Yeah - there's a question where I have about 66 votes, and the accepted answer has 40. So I figure I might get there some time. I'm hoping that since my answer didn't get accepted, I might have an opportunity to get a Gold badge for it. ;) But I'd like to see more options for "See if you can put a better answer than the accepted one", so that people try to continue discussion.

Comment: The longer the question remains open, the lower your chances of getting populist. You would have to maintain a greater ratio of YourUps vs. HisUps (even more than 2 to 1) to catch up and get your total score to 2x his. Your best opportunity is very early on (20 vs. 10 instead of 80 vs. 40)

Comment: I got min at 29 : 13 - in case any one was wondering...(they weren't)

Comment: Wouldn't you get it at 26 : 13?

Comment: "all badges should be sought after" - tumbleweed might be the only exception

Comment: Tumbleweed is StackOverflow's version of the sad music that plays on the Price Is Right when someone doesn't win.