# Can we have a kind of "super upvote" for unexpectedly awesome answers?

Tags: feature-request, up-votes, voting

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Should we have a small number of Supervotes per day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8098/should-we-have-a-small-number-of-supervotes-per-day)
>   [How to give some boost to some really good answers that arrive late?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6662/how-to-give-some-boost-to-some-really-good-answers-that-arrive-late)

I understand you can choose an answer with the checkmark, but occasionally you come across an answer that you feel deserves a heck of a lot more than that.

Maybe users can get expendable "super-upvotes". When used, these would give the target user a ton of reputation. They could be earned by obtaining enough reputation points (perhaps 1 for every X reputation you earned?)

It would provide users with more incentive to participate, as they would be getting these tangible "items" that could be used with great effect. And users who are rewarded with them would feel pretty awesome about themselves.

And for even more fun, on the darker side, a "super-downvote"...

Comment: Previously suggested here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8098/should-we-have-a-small-number-of-supervotes-per-day
and originally here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6662/how-to-give-some-boost-to-some-really-good-answers-that-arrive-late/8083#8083

Answer (score 4):

If you want to give someone an extra reward, find another *deserving* post by that user and vote for it.  Even better, if that post already has 9 votes (or 24 or 99) you can effectively give them a badge.

As for the super downvote: that's what flagging is for.

Comment: Only do that for answers that deserve the up vote.

Comment: hence _"deserving"_ in italics

Answer (score 4):

If your question is more than 2 days old, you could set up a bounty then immediately award it to that user's answer. Depending on how generous you are with your own rep, you can give the user as much as +550 rep. But this would only work for answers on questions you own (you can't reward an answer to another user's question).

A "super downvote", I guess, would be similar to the offensive/spam flag on a post. Once a post reaches 6 offensive or spam flags, it's deleted and the user that posted it is penalized 100 rep. But you'd still have to get 5 people to agree with you for it to have any effect.

Answer (score 3):

If you leave a comment on the chosen one, His disciples will either follow you in nodding or run you out of town. So, if you pour some comment honey over the answer, as to why you thought it was oar-some, or awesome even, that might help attract other upvoters to lick the skin and taste it for themselves and in effect, create a super vote by way of the community.