# How to improve the voting system?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting, fastest-gun

I have noticed many great answers with a low vote count. Sometimes I thought the best answer was voted 0 times when the first one had 100 votes.

I believe that the best answers are usually hidden at the bottom of the page because people only read (and vote) the top voted answers. Usually the top voted answers are not the best ones, but the first to appear.

how would you solve this?

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6662/how-to-give-some-boost-to-some-really-good-answers-that-arrive-late

Comment: This problem is genrically referred to as "The fastest gun in the west" problem, and has been discussed at length through a variety of questions here on meta.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem

Answer (score 3):

This is one of those things that can't be changed without serious reprocussions. If the answer is *exceptional*, it will eventually make its way to the top.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting one answer because I don't want to add this to the question. Also I want my proposals to be evaluated along other answers. I propose:

- People should evaluate over-time the answers to their questions. They should have more voting options (liking voting up/down several times) and get reputation points for their maintenance
- Maybe questions should not be sorted only by number of votes, maybe a new 0 voted answer should show along the 3 voted answers... or higher.
- New answers to old questions should show up first. Maybe something like best answer and intermediately two or three random new answers.

Comment: The latter two of your suggestions are a possible sort option already. For example, on Meta, I always sort answers by Newest.

Comment: The problem with your suggestions is that the vast, vast majority of visitors (like > 99%) are **looking** for answers (not answering). For that 99%, the top answers almost *have* to be shown first so the "best answer" == the most visible.

Answer (score 0):

What you're complaining about is a people problem (i.e. when looking quickly through a lot of content I don't bother to look at a great many answers on most questions).

Trying to solve people problems with technology fixes either

- doesn't work.

or

- annoys the users.

Moreover, if you think that an answer with a hundred votes is worse than one with very few I am forced to assume you're talking about some subjective question and **I really couldn't care less**.