# Ability to vote more than once on a question

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to give some boost to some really good answers that arrive late?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6662/how-to-give-some-boost-to-some-really-good-answers-that-arrive-late)
>   [Should we have a small number of Supervotes per day?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8098/should-we-have-a-small-number-of-supervotes-per-day)

[In which versions of the C++ standard does "(i+=10)+=10" have undefined behaviour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655290/in-c-does-i-10-10-result-in-undefined-behaviour)

The highest voted answer to that question is good and accurate.  It's tempting to vote it up and it rather deserves it.

The lowest voted answer is much, much better.  It cites each applicable clause in the standard but it's got less than half the points at the time of this writing.

Since votes order the questions and tend to tell the inquirer and other observers which answer the community thought was best...it's hard to give both votes and I'm stuck having to give a vote to the one I think is best, especially since it's so low on the voting block (maybe due to timing, maybe due to lack of understanding...who knows) I don't want to push the other answer even further above it.

So that other answer isn't getting my vote even though I think it's good.  If I was able to distribute a "good answer" vote and a "best answer" vote...with the latter counting for two...or just be able to give two for an answer, I think that would encourage me to up-vote more answers.

Comment: If that also gives me a super charged down vote, I'll fully support it.

Comment: @YannisRizos great idea! now, what about _negative bounty_? I'd give some `-rep` to [Goma](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3457/how-did-this-user-amass-more-than-2k-worth-of-reputation)

Comment: @gnatakaspecialagentMulder Don't remind me of that guy... Three socks already after his suspension (all caught and banned).

Comment: Come on guys...can't you get me into negative rep?  Yous all is slow.

Comment: Come on guys...can't you read the [FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)? Yous all is lazy.

Answer (score 8):

There is no need for this. Just upvote those answers you think are good. Your view on what is the better/best answer does not matter anyway. If you really have a preference, see "Can I award a bounty to an old answer?" in [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) But the OP gets to decide what is the most helpful to him/her in the end.

If there is a clear winner, given enough time it will most likely end up on top. And if not, there is no real harm done.

Answer (score 3):

Upvote this answer, leave a comment on this question with a link to the answer you want double upvoted, and I'll upvote it for you! Limited to one double upvote per person. Offer not valid in the United States of America or Europe.

Some restrictions apply. Most notably, that I will not actually do this. See your local Honda dealer for details.