# Show an index of answers, and allow answers to have a title

Tags: discussion, feature-request

This is funky, likely impossible, so treat it as highly speculative fun.

For every question, near the top, I'd like to see an index of the answers like so:

Sample question: [What is the native keyword in Java for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101311/what-is-the-native-keyword-in-java-for/30635871)

Sample index:

```
Answer title and link  Vote count   Date (years ago)   Author rep
Minimal example        1000000      5                  100000
Newb introduction      100000       4                  100000
Java 3 changes all     10000        0                  10
Standards              100          5                  100
Performance            10           3                  10
Internals of internals 1            1                  1
```

Where the title is a new property of answers, and if left empty, either:

- use the first sentence / N words of the body.

  This breaks old answers which started with something like "I know this is an old question but ..." and many more.
- leave empty and let the upvotes speak for themselves

  Even without a title, it would be a good way to spot recent answers that have lots of upvotes or by high rep users.

The advantage is that it would be really easy to jump directly to the answer that best fits your needs.

Yes, this is only useful for questions that have a lot of answers.

Yes, many of those are too broad and should be closed.

But many aren't, e.g. my sample question. And maybe the definition of broad would become... broader as a result of this change.

The number of answers tends to infinity on every question, so sooner or later we have to deal with that.

So this would help for: [How to give some boost to some really good answers that arrive late?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6662/how-to-give-some-boost-to-some-really-good-answers-that-arrive-late)

Maybe this overlaps with the new Documentations feature to which I haven't been granted a beta. But it would be more elegant if we could treat both use cases with the same system if possible.